# Excel Number to Word shows Four Hundred and Fifty Fifteen and Not Four Hundred and Fifty Five

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a UDF that spells numbers into words. The issue I'm having is that when I type in a number between 11-19 I run into the issue of it being spelt as "OneTwo" for 12 etc

This is my code:

```
Function NumInHundredsThousandsMillions(IPNum As Long)
If IPNum > 999999999 Then NumInHundredsThousandsMillions = "ERROR": Exit Function

Dim TempNum As Long
Dim Num(1 To 3)
Dim Dig1, Dig2, Pos
Dim IpnumTxt As String, StrHun As String, Str2digit As String, TempStr As String
Dim T As Long
Dig1 = Array("", "One ", "Two ", "Three ", "Four ", "Five ", "Six ", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine ", "Ten ", _
        "Eleven ", "Twelve ", "Thirteen ", "Fourteen ", "Fifteen ", "Sixteen ", "Seventeen ", "Eighteen ", "Nineteen ")

Dig2 = Array("", "", "Twenty ", "Thirty ", "Fourty ", "Fifty ", "Sixty ", "Seventy ", "Eighty ", "Ninety ")

Pos = Array("", "Million ", "Thousand ", "")

Num(1) = Int(IPNum / 1000000)
Num(2) = Int((IPNum - Num(1) * 1000000) / 1000)
Num(3) = IPNum Mod 1000

For T = 1 To 3
 If Num(T) > 0 Then
 If Len(Num(T)) = 3 Then StrHun = Dig1(Int(Num(T) / 100)) & "Hundred "
 Num(T) = Right(Num(T), 2) + 0
 Str2digit = Dig2(Int(Num(T) / 10)) & Dig1(Num(T) Mod 10)
    If T = 3 And StrHun <> "" And Str2digit <> "" Then StrHun = StrHun & "and "
    TempStr = TempStr & StrHun & Str2digit & Pos(T)
 End If
Next T
NumInHundredsThousandsMillions = TempStr
End Function
```

Everything functions as it should but If a number is from 11-19 it will say "OneTwo" for 12, etc.

The other thing I'd like to achieve for a number like 555,555 I would like it to say "Five Hundred **and** Fifty Five Thousand Five Hundred and Fifty Five" and not Five Hundred Fifty Five Thousand Five Hundred and Fifty Five - I can't seem to work out how to add this in without other numbers being affected with my code

Comment: Overall structure:  you ought to write a subroutine to translate 0 - 999.  You can call it three times; once with the millions group, once with the thousands group, and lastly with the units group appending the appropriate unit to its result.

Comment: Will you also be passing values with decimals or only number?

Comment: Not an answer - if you're using this as a worksheet function you can change the error return to `CVErr(xlErrValue)` to return an #VALUE error as long as the function returns a variant (which it does as you've not defined what it should return).